# Find all real number x such that [2,-1,3] and [x,-2,1] are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find all real number x such that [2,-1,3] and [x,-2,1] are orthogonal.

I saw an example that just simply used dot product

$[2, -1, 3] \cdot [x, -2, 1]$ = $2x + 2 + 3 = 2x + 5$

The two vectors will be orthogonal when this dot product is zero. I'm not understanding the question all too well because apparently it is orthogonal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the two vectors are orthogonal if and only if the dot product is zero. From that you find that they are orthogonal if and only if $x = -\frac{5}{2}$. And that's it basically.